# How do I set an icon for the whole application using PyGObject

Tags: python, gtk3

I have a very simple app in python and using GTK3 for gui. I just want to set a default icon for it, so it shoes in Dash in Gnome-shell.

I'm desperate, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I used this code:

```
Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Window title")
icon=("firefox")
pixbuf24 = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default().load_icon(icon, 24, 0)
pixbuf32 = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default().load_icon(icon, 32, 0)
pixbuf48 = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default().load_icon(icon, 48, 0)
pixbuf64 = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default().load_icon(icon, 64, 0)
pixbuf96 = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default().load_icon(icon, 96, 0)
self.set_icon_list([pixbuf24, pixbuf32, pixbuf48, pixbuf64, pixbuf96]);
```

I don't get any error messages, but yet, no icon is shown. I chose **firefox** for testing and to make sure the icon exists.

Can someone help me figure out why isn't the icon showing?

P.S.
I tried to run the code from @morningbird on my computer, but the icon still doesn't appear in Dash.

[Icon is shown in the window, but not in Dash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99wt5.png)

I have to leave the screenshot as link, as I am not allowed to include pictures here.

Comment: If you were to inspect that pixbufs can you be sure that icon loaded properly? I run that code and it worked just fine.

Comment: So it did set the icon for the application for you @morningbird ? Even in Dash in Gnome-shell? How can I inspect the pixbufs? Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Yes, also in Dash in Gnome-shell, that is DE I'm using. And I just also displayed one of the pixbufs icon in IconViewer inside the window but a proper python debuger should let you inspect the object on runtime.

Comment: I'll post the code as an answer since comments don't allow for multi line code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the cause of the problem.

It is **Wayland**.  The code works fine under X11, but doesn't on Wayland. Thank you again @morningbird for your help. I was already going crazy. When I asked the question, I had no idea that that would make any difference.

To get it working in Wayland, you have to use

`GLib.set_prgname('app_name')`

**app_name** has to correspond to the **exec=** entry in the corresponding `*.desktop` file. After that, the **name=** will be used for the application name and **icon=** will be used for the icon in Dash.

Comment: Damn, I knew about that thing in Wayland. Had issues with it in my personal app. I was sure it doesn't affect setting Gtk.Window icon programmatically, just desktop file association.

Comment: Also you should mark your answer as correct for the question.

Comment: A single windows is not an application, and besides that, why don't you just use ˋset_icon_nameˋ?

Answer (score 2):

I decided to test the code as it looked as if it should work correctly. I incorporated your logic into Gtk.Window with additional IconViewer to see the icon loaded into one of the pixbufs.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository.GdkPixbuf import Pixbuf

icon = ("firefox")

class IconViewWindow(Gtk.Window):

  def __init__(self):
    Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
    self.set_default_size(200, 200)

    liststore = Gtk.ListStore(Pixbuf, str)
    iconview = Gtk.IconView.new()
    iconview.set_model(liststore)
    iconview.set_pixbuf_column(0)
    iconview.set_text_column(1)

    pixbuf24 = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default().load_icon(icon, 24, 0)
    pixbuf32 = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default().load_icon(icon, 32, 0)
    pixbuf48 = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default().load_icon(icon, 48, 0)
    pixbuf64 = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default().load_icon(icon, 64, 0)
    pixbuf96 = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default().load_icon(icon, 96, 0)
    self.set_icon_list([pixbuf24, pixbuf32, pixbuf48, pixbuf64, pixbuf96])
    liststore.append([pixbuf64, "firefox"])

    self.add(iconview)

win = IconViewWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Running it with python3 under Gnome 3.24 it resulted with proper display of icon for the Gtk.Window in dash and all DE elements.

[image: Application window]

[image: App in dash]

**Edit:**

Maybe doing a proper icon discovery (since you currently aren't usuing self installed icons) might help to get some insight.

```
icon_name = "firefox"
icon_theme = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default()

found_icons = set()
for res in range(24, 32, 48, 64, 96):
    icon = icon_theme.lookup_icon(icon_name, res, 0)
    #print(icon)
    if icon != None:
        found_icons.add(icon.get_filename())

if len(found_icons) > 0:
    print("\n".join(found_icons))
    sizes = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default().get_icon_sizes(icon_name)
    max_size = max(sizes)
    print("max size = {} ({})".format(max_size, sizes))
    pixbuf = icon_theme.load_icon(icon_name, max_size, 0)
    self.set_default_icon_list([pixbuf])
```

**Edit 2:**

Generally speaking doing `Gtk.Window.set_icon_name("icon-name")` is a better way to use installed icons as all the icon size choices will be handled for you. Using `Gtk.Windowset_default_icon_list([pixbufs])` is a good option when using local PNG icons of set sizes.

I would be surprised if the issue was not with "firefox" icon availability as those methods are well documented and tested.

Comment: Thank you @morningbird for your help!

I just tried to run your example, and this is what I've got. It still doesn't work as expected.

Comment: [Icon is shown in the window, but not in Dash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99wt5.png)

I have to leave the screenshot as link, as I am not allowed to include pictures here.

Comment: I edited the answer. That is the only thing more I can add. Other way is to set the app id and install desktop entry. Also check if `self.set_icon_name("firefox")` works?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @morningbird ! I really do appreciate it. I will post my results as soon as I have some results. `self.set_icon_name("firefox")` doesn't set the icon either. I even tried to change the icon theme, but with no better results

Comment: Are there any GTK warnings in the output? I am sorry but I don't think I know how to help. Other then saying - this always worked for me. I am clueless about what can be the issue here. Maybe you should also test with default Adwaita icon pack?

Comment: I totally agree with you. I was almost going crazy. As your example worked for you, but doesn't work for me, the issue might be much deeper than a missing icon. The icons are there. I even tried to change the theme. I'll try it in Fluxbox when can, and I'll pay the results here. Could you try the whole app if I post it here?